# Narrow characters

Tags: bash, python, gnome-terminal, special-characters

It would be awesome to modify [spark](https://github.com/holman/spark) to print narrow characters in for example Gnome Terminal. Is this at all possible with Bash / Python?

Comment: By "narrow characters" you mean literally characters of lower width than normal letters?

Comment: Yes. Is there another definition of "narrow"?

Comment: I think there is, but don't recall it - so I wanted to clarify.

Comment: ...There definitely is a special meaning for [a wide character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character) and that made me a bit confused about "narrow".

Comment: Thanks all. Answers as expected, but I just wanted to make sure. You never know what's possible :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. While [VT100-compatible](http://vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html) terminals do have support for double-width lines (using the DECDWL control sequence), they don't have support for narrow lines or characters.

Answer (score 3):

As I read the source of `spark`, I can see it just uses the special ASCII characters as "ticks" - so, in general, the answer is **no**, because that would need the *font* to be changed on-the fly. Well, maybe you *could* actually use a special, non-fxed-width font defined, for example, as the *italics* or **bold** font for the terminal, but that would be a one-time andjustment (choosing the font) and would affect all terminal output that'd normally be printed in italics/bold - and that is definitely not desirable.